# Auto-click again after 3 seconds after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Auto-click again after 3 seconds after click. Why don't work?

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name='submit']", setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).trigger('click');
}, 3000));
```

Comment: Why are you returning true inside the timeout? The click trigger will never be reached

Comment: Why is there a `return true;` in the function?  That would prevent the rest of the function from executing.

Comment: setTimeout returns an id. and is run inline. what you have here is `$(document).on('click', selector, 123);`

Comment: Why dont submit click after 3 sek?

Comment: You want to auto click on button after every 3 second only once or looping ?

Comment: @Mohammad Only one, for submit form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect which click event is manual and which is automatically. So define `timer` variable to do this work. If `timer` equal to `false` that mean click is manual and if be `true` mean is automatically.

*Note that when `setTimeout` callback is called the `this` refer to window, so you need to store `this` is variable (`ele`)*

```js
var timer = false;
$(document).on("click", "input[name='submit']", function(e){
  var ele = this;
  // First click
  if (!timer){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(ele).prop("disabled", true)
    setTimeout(function(){
      timer = true;
      $(ele).prop("disabled", false).trigger('click');
    }, 3000)
  // Second click
  } else {
    console.log("Submit form");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="click">
```

Comment: If second click that prop disabled and after click submit?

Comment: @php If you mean user click before ending 3s, check updated

Comment: If to send the form after 3 seconds after the first click.

Comment: The form will be send after 3s and when showing **Submit form** console message

Comment: Does not send data and does not reload the page as usual sign of successful submission.

Comment: @php You should put your submitting code instead of `console` in `else`

Comment: What is work?
$("input[name='submit']").trigger("click"); and document.getElementById('addsubmit').submit(); doesnt work.

Comment: Doesnt work for me. Maybe form by id? Why not reload the page?

Comment: @php The `submit()` work on `form`. So you should select form instead of button. The `#addsubmit` should be form

Comment: How to put the id form if there are several forms on the page?

Comment: @php You can't use duplicate `id` attribute in html. Set different `id` for target form

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems with your code:

First, your are putting your setTimeout in for your callback. setTimeout returns an int id for the timer it spawns. 
So essentially what you have now is:

```
.on('click', selector, 123);
```

which obviously won't work.
If you want your code to execute later on, put the setTimeout *inside* of the callback.

```
.on('click', selector, function() {
  setTimeout(myFunc, 3000);
});
```

then your callback runs on click, and spawns the timer.

Secondly, I assume you want `this` inside of the callback to refer to the clicked object, and not `window`.. so you'll have to pass a thisArg to setTimeout or define it in the parent scope.. or use arrow functions which don't bind a new thisArg. For simplicity I suggest using arrow functions.

```
setTimeout( () => {
  $(this).trigger('click');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: It is necessary after the click, 3 seconds have passed, the button has gone - this is necessary for the timeliness of downloading images

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a question or a general explanation. but what I have explained here will allow you to do that.